# Meaning of "artfully indeterminate" in this excerpt from The Lies of Locke Lamora?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, vocabulary, literature

I recently started reading The Lies of Locke Lamora by Scott Lynch and was confronted with "artfully indeterminate" in the following context:

[ What say you? Are you the helpful sort? Are you willing to assist your new brothers and sisters with their interesting work?”
The boy mulled this over for a few seconds.
“You mean,” he said in a high thin voice, “that you want us to steal things.”
The old man stared down at the little boy for a very long time while a number of the Shades’ Hill orphans giggled behind their hands.
“Yes,” the Thiefmaker said at last, nodding slowly. “*I might just mean that—though you have a very, ahhh, uncompromising view of a certain exercise of personal initiative that we prefer to frame in more **artfully indeterminate** terms.* Not that I expect that to mean anything to you. What’s your name, boy?”
“Lamora.” ]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

He means that they don't call it thievery or put a specific name on it (indeterminate), and he indicates that considers this use of euphamism clever (artful).